# Uncaught DOMException Failed to execute 'define' Polymer

Tags: polymer

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': "undefined" is not a valid custom element name...

My Custom Element is named resume-app
Someone mentioned on a different post that that may be the reason why it failed so I am wondering what else I could have done wrong?

The webpage loads all the elements correctly just the console is littered with these exceptions.

Comment: Can you post the code as well?

Comment: Figured out a fix, I had an older version of web components, So after deleting and reinstalling the components, it worked fine. Thank you all though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the webcomponents package, older versions are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the function name in the script:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is:  'logout-element',
        logout: function() {
            this.$.logoutEndpoint.go();
        },
        logoutResponse: function() {
            this.fire("logout");
        },
        logoutError: function() {
            this.$.errorToast.text="Logout Service Error";
            this.$.errorToast.show();
        }
    });
</script>
```